# What does "Data Updated" field at the bottom of the TFS Report tell us?

Tags: tfs, reporting-services

At the bottom-right of each of the canned TFS reports there are three fields

[image]

What is the "Data Updated" field represent?

Is it the last time the the cube was updated?

Is it the last time that someone updated a work item that is included in the report?

I found the following link indicating that it was the "freshness" of the data but that doesn't really answer my questions.

[TFS 2010 - Reporting Services Reports](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sunder/archive/2010/02/23/reporting-in-team-foundation-server-2010-part-6-rich-sql-reporting-services-reports.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the last time the cube was updated.

Comment: Is there any documentation that you can provide to support this answer? I believe that you are correct but when I share this information with others I will need some documentation to back it up.

Comment: I cannot find the documentation. But I am sure about this. It is the field in the cube when it was last calculated. Be aware that some of the reports come from the warehouse which is updated more ferequently (by default every hour), while the cube is updated by default every two hours. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244706